# SharePoint 2010 People Search Results with Managed Properties returns GUID

Tags: xslt, people-search, managed-property, crawled-property, guid

I have been tasked with adding some extra phone numbers to our SharePoint 2010 People Search results. To do this, I have created some custom Managed Properties, and mapped them to the relevant Crawled properties.

Mappings in Profile Service (These have to be Multi Value Properties):

[image: Mapped Profile Properties]

Mappings in the Search Service:

[image: Mobile Mapping]
[image: Office Mapping]

I have set up the Search results web part to contain the following fetched properties :

[image: Columns]

The XSL file has these additions :

[image: Check]

[image: Mobile XSL]
[image: Office XSL]

But there seems to be a strange issue with some results (I redacted the working results):

[image]

For some reason, there is a GUID in some search results instead of a phone number. This is not happening on every result, but just on some of them.

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this. At first I thought it was caused by mapping the `ows_taxId_***` crawled property, but after removing that from the mapping and re-crawling the issue remains.

I need to get rid of these GUIDs from the results, and display the proper values. I'm not sure where they come from...

On the Profile Page, there is no such issue :

[image: Profile is ok]

Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue actually fixed itself. Not sure of the cause, but the issue has gone.